# PHP pass in $this to function outside class

Tags: php, this

Can you pass in a $this variable to use in a function in the "global" space like you can in javascript?  I know $this is meant for classes, but just wondering.  I'm trying to avoid using the "global" keyword.

For example:

```
class Example{
  function __construct(){ }
  function test(){ echo 'something'; }
}

function outside(){ var_dump($this); $this->test(); }

$example = new Example();

call_user_func($example, 'outside', array('of parameters')); //Where I'm passing in an object to be used as $this for the function
```

In javascript I can use the `call` method and assign a `this` variable to be used for a function.  Was just curious if the same sort of thing can be accomplished with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is very much different from JavaScript. JS is a prototype based language whereas PHP is an object oriented one. Injecting a different `$this` in a class method doesn't make sense in PHP.

What you may be looking for is injecting a different `$this` into a closure (anonymous function). This will be possible using the upcoming PHP version 5.4. See the [object extension RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/object-extension).

(By the way you can indeed inject a `$this` into a class which is not `instanceof self`. But as I already said, this doesn't make no sense at all.)

Comment: X-Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943486/restrict-what-can-create-a-php-class/3944238#3944238

Comment: As a very late "just to clear things up" comment: Both PHP and JS are fully object oriented. The difference lies in the *type* of object system each one uses. PHP uses a *class based* object system (as many other languages do), JavaScript uses a *prototype based* object system (which could emulate a class based one if you really want it to). But both are fully fledged object oriented languages.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would just pass it as a reference:

```
class Example{
  function __construct(){ }
  function test(){ echo 'something'; }
}

function outside(&$obj){ var_dump($obj); $obj->test(); }

$example = new Example();

call_user_func_array('outside', array(&$example));
```

It would kind of defeat the purpose of private and protected vars, to be able to access "$this" of an obj from outside of the code. "$this", "self", and "parent" are keywords exclusive to specific objects that they're being used in.

Comment: Why as reference? I would normally pass it just as an object identifier *value*.

Comment: Why are you duplicating answers?

Comment: This is actually a different answer. Notice the shiny-fancy addition of references? You can also create a static registry class, which would hold all of your objects, which is the direction I would take. I believe newer versions of PHP automatically passes references for cases like these, but it's best to force them imo, for older versions. Iirc, you would want to make it a reference so that your class isn't read only, and also for memory management purposes.