# Get number of parameters a function requires

Tags: php, class, reflection

This is an extension question of [PHP pass in $this to function outside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774444/php-pass-in-this-to-function-outside-class)

And I believe this is what I'm looking for but it's in python not php: [Programmatically determining amount of parameters a function requires - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741950/programatically-determining-amount-of-parameters-a-function-requires-python)

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
function client_func($cls, $arg){ }
```

and when I'm ready to call this function I might do something like this in pseudo code:

```
if function's first parameter equals '$cls', then call client_func(instanceof class, $arg)
else call client_func($arg)
```

So basically, is there a way to lookahead to a function and see what parameter values are required before calling the function?

I guess this would be like `debug_backtrace()`, but the other way around.

`func_get_args()` can only be called from within a function which doesn't help me here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [Reflection](http://php.net/book.reflection), especially [ReflectionFunction](http://php.net/class.reflectionfunction) in your case.

```
$fct = new ReflectionFunction('client_func');
echo $fct->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
```

As far as I can see you will find [getParameters()](http://php.net/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters) useful too

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful when attempting to write some functional concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Only way is with reflection by going to https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

```
class foo {
 function bar ($arg1, $arg2) {
   // ...
 }
}

$method = new ReflectionMethod('foo', 'bar');
$num = $method->getNumberOfParameters();
```