# Get method number of parameters in php

Tags: php, reflection, methods

I'm have code that return service description object for `JSON-RPC` and I have similar problem then this: [PHP: Get number of parameters a function requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774740/php-get-number-of-parameters-a-function-requires) but instead of function I have a method.

```
function service_description($object) {
    $class = get_class($object);
    $methods = get_class_methods($class);
    $service = array("sdversion" => "1.0",
                     "name" => "DemoService",
                     "address" => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
                     "id" => "urn:md5:" . md5($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        $service['procs'][] = array(
            "name" => $method,
            "params" => ?????
        );
    }
    return $service;
}
```

How can I check parameters of each method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found, there is class for this [ReflectionMethod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php).

```
foreach ($methods as $method_name) {
    $proc = array("name" => $method_name);
    $method = new ReflectionMethod($class, $method_name);
    $params = array();
    foreach ($method->getParameters() as $param) {
        $params[] = $param->name;
    }
    $proc['params'] = $params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the reflection class.

```
$rclass = new ReflectionClass('ClassName');
$method = $rclass->getMethod('methodName');
$method->getNumberOfRequiredParameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with this one: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofparameters.php