# PHP Array of Methods and Parameters

Tags: php, arrays

I'm passing an array of methods and parameters to my object. The array can be any size with any number of methods and/or parameters. In between the methods are the parameters.

**EDIT: Sorry that this was not clear. The parameters following a method are for THAT method. So in the first example below method1 has two parameters (param1 and param2), method2 has two parameters (param1 and param2) and method3 has one parameter (param).**

Here are some examples:

```
array = ["method1","param1","param2","method2","param1","param2","method3","param"];
array = ["method1","param1","param2","method2","param"];
array = ["method","param"];
```

I can pull the methods from the array using method_exists but I'm trying to pull the parameters from the array. This is what I've got so far:

```
    // Loop thru $array to find methods
    $methods = array();
    for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if(method_exists($this,$array[$i]) === TRUE) {
               $methods[] = $i;
        }
    }
    // Get parameters for methods

    // If there is only one method take the remaining array values
    // else get the parameters in between the methods
    if(count($methods) == 1) {
        $parameters = array_slice($array,1,count($array));  
    } else {
        ??
    }
```

**How can I grab the array values for parameters that match up to the methods when the array values for methods are variable?**

Comment: as i understood, the parameters are for the methods? If so, you should go throu the array, each time, you find a method, get number of requered parameters and then -> if the next x entries are not methods, they are parameters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774740/php-get-number-of-parameters-a-function-requires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but I believe you only want to process the array once. Remember - all of your array values are either "methods" OR "parameters". Therefore, if you are able to find "methods", you can also find "parameters".

```
$methods = array();
$parameters = array();
$curParameters = null;
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if(method_exists($this,$array[$i]) === TRUE) {
           //associate last set of paremeters with method
           if ($curParameters != null) {
               $parameters[] = $curParameters;
           }
           //new method, new curParams
           $methods[] = $i;
           $curParameters = array();
    } else {
         //$array[$i] must be a parameter for the last method found
         $curParameters[] = $array[$i];
    }
}
//need to save the last set params founds
$parametres[] = $curParameters
```

When this is done parsing, you should have two arrays. The first array is `$methods` and the second is `$parameters`. These arrays should match up 1 to 1, meaning `$parameters[x]` should match up with `$methods[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just turn

```
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if(method_exists($this,$array[$i]) === TRUE) {
           $methods[] = $i;
    }
}
```

To

```
$j = 0;
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if(method_exists($this,$array[$i]) === TRUE) {
           $methods[] = $i;
           $j++;
    }
    else {
        $parameters[$j][] = $array[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also close, but I believe your j++ is in the wrong spot. Your indexes will be off by one! $methods[0] will match to $parameters[1]. (assuming the parameters come after the method in the array)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do here is check if the value you are pulling out is in your methods array.  If it is, then you know it is a method and not a parameter.  if it isn't then you know it to be a parameter.

I would use the `array_search()` php method to accomplish this.

so you code would look something like:

```
for($x=0;$x<count($array);$x++)
{
    if( array_search($array[$x], $methods) !== false)
    {
         //This is a Parameter
    }
}
```

You can find more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you have an array of methods and parameters, and you want to separate these - presumably into separate arrays.

If so, you can try the following simplified example:

```
<?php

// example object with some public methods...
class Foo
{
    function method1() {}
    function method2() {}
    function method3() {}
}

// list of methods and params
$array = [
    'method1', 
    'param1', 
    'param2', 
    'method2', 
    'param3', 
    'method3', 
    'param4', 
    'param5',
];

// get a list of Foo's methods
$methods = get_class_methods('Foo');

// array_diff to get the params only
$params = array_diff($array, $methods);

print_r($params);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [1] => param1
    [2] => param2
    [4] => param3
    [6] => param4
    [7] => param5
)
```

YMMV - this example is outside the context of the object, so `get_class_methods()` can only see public methods. It can be used inside an object to get protected and private methods too. It depends on your exact use case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to build $parameters array when building $methods array. But if for some unkown reasons, you want to keep your code as is, here is a way to do it:

```
$methods = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if(method_exists($this,$array[$i]) === TRUE) {
           $methods[] = $i;
    }
}

if(count($methods) == 1) {
    $parameters = array_slice($array,1,count($array));  
} else {
    $parameters = array();
    for ($k=0; $k < (count($methods) - 1); $k++)
        $parameters[$k] = array_slice($array,$methods[$k]+1,$methods[$k+1]-$methods[$k]-1);
    $parameters[$k] = array_slice($array,$methods[$k]+1,count($methods)-$methods[$k]-1);
}
print_r($parameters);
```